# Batch File SIP ALG test

Tags: file, batch-file, testing, sip, voip

The below line has a program that runs like a batch file.

I'm needing to create something similar that can run as just a batch file to 
test for SIP or ALG.

https://kb.iplogin.ca/hc/en-us/articles/360003299092-Prepare-Your-Network-for-Phones-line-test-ports-and-protocols-

I work at for a Telecommunications company and it would be a great tool for us to use. - Many thanks

[image]

Comment: On that page: TCP Ports:

80, 443, 8001 (for web UI)
5060 (SIP)
5061 (SIP TLS)
9002 (Web Socket used for features like Web Phone and Portal Video)
UDP Ports:

5060 (SIP)
20000-27999 (RTP Media)

Comment: Well, why not just download that executable and use it? But, to get to my actual point, let's say someone writes something for you, do you expect it to be free?

Answer (score 1):

There are plenty of such tools exists. For example http://sipp.sourceforge.net/

No point write just enother tool.

Just create scenario for sipp and check out result.